# Laravel Mix (Vue + Stylus). Blank page on npm run watch

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, stylus, laravel-5.5

I start up a new Laravel + Vue + Stylus project, and i can't normally work because i always got blank page when adding/editing some styles on .styl files. And when i edit my .vue templates it come back to normal state.

My main.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import { routes } from './routes/index';
import App from './App.vue';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router =  new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
});
```

My webpack.mix.js file:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/main.js', 'public/js')
      .stylus('resources/assets/stylus/app.styl', 'public/css')
      .browserSync('localhost:8000');
```

Some strange thing that i noticed is that when i save my .styl file i got main.js like prod version(not compiled) and in console has an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

If i save this file again i got normal compiled main.js file, but it doesn't render my App

And finally when i edit .vue templates all works perfect.

Comment: Is there an error in in the terminal/cli after it's complied.

Comment: terminal is clear, no errors

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm running into the same issue.